# Identifier for nested loops?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

right now I am learning about nested loops in PL/SQL.
To distinguish the loops I have to use marks like "outer_loop"and 
"inner_loop".

My Question:

What happens when I have more than two loops which are nested? What would be the identifier of the third loop for example? Maybe "inner_inner_loop"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "To distinguish the loops I have to use marks" Emm.. can you elaborate?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us your code.

Comment: I think you talk about labels. There's no definite answer to this question. You can use anything you like. `inner_inner_loop` or `loop_level_two` or `iii` or `two` or whatever. That's up to you. It's opinion based with what one comes up with or prefers, etc..

Comment: It's like you are asking how to name your variables. It's down to preference. If you have a lot of nested loops I suggest being descriptive like: `what_are_you_looping` + `_loop`.

Answer (score 1):

By "marks" you mean what Oracle calls labels. Labels are free text, and you can use any words you like. It is best to use something which describes the purpose of the loop: `outer_loop`, `innr_loop` are a bit meh. Labels are an opportunity to make our code clearer, so make the most of it.

The following is just a demonstration of how to use labels. I am not suggesting this is the best way to implement the code. Indeed, lots of nested loops is often a red flag.

```
<< departments >>
for d_rec in ( select * from dept ) loop 
  ..
  << employees >>
  for e_rec in ( select * from emp where emp.deptno = d_rec.dept_no ) loop
    ..
    << projects >>
    for p_rec in ( select * from proj where proj.empno = e_rec.emp_no ) loop
      ..
    end loop projects;
  end loop employees;
end loop departments;
```